# How can one duplicate columns N times in DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image]I have a dataframe with one column and I would like to get a Dataframe with N columns all of which will be identical to the first one. I can simply duplicate it by:

```
df[['new column name']] = df[['column name']]
```

but I have to make more than 1000 identical columns that's why it doesnt work
. One important thing is figures in columns should change for instance if first columns is 0 the nth column is n and the previous is n-1

Comment: Use a loop.....

Answer (score 4):

If it's a single column, you can use tranpose and then simply replicate them with `pd.concat` and tranpose back to the original format, this avoids looping and should be faster, then you can change the column names in a second line, but without dealing with all the data in the dataframe which would be the most consuming performance wise:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column':[1,2,3,4,5]})
```

Original dataframe:

```
   Column
0       1
1       2
2       3
3       4
4       5
df = pd.concat([df.T]*1000).T
```

Output:

```
   Column  Column  Column  Column  ...  Column  Column  Column  Column
0       1       1       1       1  ...       1       1       1       1
1       2       2       2       2  ...       2       2       2       2
2       3       3       3       3  ...       3       3       3       3
3       4       4       4       4  ...       4       4       4       4
4       5       5       5       5  ...       5       5       5       5

[5 rows x 1000 columns]

df.columns = ['Column'+'_'+str(i) for i in range(1000)]
```

Comment: To make this work I instead did df = pd.concat([df]*1000, axis=1), I think this is the most interpretable answer though.

Answer (score 1):

Say that you have a `df:`, with column name 'company_name' that consists of 8 companies:

```
df = {"company_name":{"0":"Telia","1":"Proximus","2":"Tmobile","3":"Orange","4":"Telefonica","5":"Verizon","6":"AT&T","7":"Koninklijke"}}

  company_name
0        Telia
1     Proximus
2      Tmobile
3       Orange
4   Telefonica
5      Verizon
6         AT&T
7  Koninklijke
```

You can use a `loop` and `range` to determine how many identical columns to create, and do:

```
for i in range(0,1000):
    df['company_name'+str(i)] = df['company_name']
```

which results in the `shape` of the `df`:

```
df.shape
(8, 1001)
```

i.e. it replicated 1000 times the same columns. The names of the `duplicated` columns will be the same as the original one, plus an integer (=+1) at the end:

```
'company_name', 'company_name0', 'company_name1', 'company_name2','company_name..N'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df

   A  B  C
0  x  x  x
1  y  x  z
```

Duplicate column "C" 5 times using `df.assign`:

```
n = 5
df2 = df.assign(**{f'C{i}': df['C'] for i in range(1, n+1)})
df2

   A  B  C C1 C2 C3 C4 C5
0  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x
1  y  x  z  z  z  z  z  z
```

Set `n` to 1000 to get your desired output.

---

You can also directly assign the result back:

```
df[[f'C{i}' for i in range(1, n+1)]] = df[['C']*n].to_numpy()
df
 
   A  B  C C1 C2 C3 C4 C5
0  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x
1  y  x  z  z  z  z  z  z
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the most efficient is to index with [`DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) instead of using an outer loop

```
n = 3
new_df = df.loc[:, ['column_duplicate']*n + 
                   df.columns.difference(['column_duplicate']).tolist()]
print(new_df)

   column_duplicate  column_duplicate  column_duplicate  other
0                 0                 0                 0     10
1                 1                 1                 1     11
2                 2                 2                 2     12
3                 3                 3                 3     13
4                 4                 4                 4     14
5                 5                 5                 5     15
6                 6                 6                 6     16
7                 7                 7                 7     17
8                 8                 8                 8     18
9                 9                 9                 9     19
```

**If you want add a suffix**

```
suffix_tup = ('a', 'b', 'c')

not_dup_cols = df.columns.difference(['column_duplicate']).tolist()

new_df = (df.loc[:, ['column_duplicate']*len(suffix_tup) + 
                    not_dup_cols]
            .set_axis(list(map(lambda suffix: f'column_duplicate_{suffix}', 
                               suffix_tup)) + 
                      not_dup_cols, axis=1)
         )
print(new_df)


   column_duplicate_a  column_duplicate_b  column_duplicate_c  other
0                   0                   0                   0     10
1                   1                   1                   1     11
2                   2                   2                   2     12
3                   3                   3                   3     13
4                   4                   4                   4     14
5                   5                   5                   5     15
6                   6                   6                   6     16
7                   7                   7                   7     17
8                   8                   8                   8     18
```

---

**or add an index**

```
n = 3
not_dup_cols = df.columns.difference(['column_duplicate']).tolist()

new_df = (df.loc[:, ['column_duplicate']*n + 
                    not_dup_cols]
            .set_axis(list(map(lambda x: f'column_duplicate_{x}', range(n))) + 
                      not_dup_cols, axis=1)
         )
print(new_df)

   column_duplicate_0  column_duplicate_1  column_duplicate_2  other
0                   0                   0                   0     10
1                   1                   1                   1     11
2                   2                   2                   2     12
3                   3                   3                   3     13
4                   4                   4                   4     14
5                   5                   5                   5     15
6                   6                   6                   6     16
7                   7                   7                   7     17
8                   8                   8                   8     18
9                   9                   9                   9     19
```